# Mysql and node: Running query in parallel

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a rest api that takes 3 query and return the data in json format to front end of angular. However the query takes almost 1 min to run and send the json format. Can anyone help me to optimize the code so that I can get a better running time.

Here is the code:

```
async function getChartData (req, res){
    try{

        var sqlquery=" " 
        var sqlsecond=" "
        var sqlthird=" "

        let result1 = await selectquery(sqlquery)

        let result2 = await selectquery(sqlsecond)

        let result3 = await selectquery(sqlthird)

        return res.json({result1:result1, result2:result2, result3:result3});

    }
    catch(err){
        // response.status(500).end();
        console.log(err);
    }
  }


async function selectquery(sqlquery){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mysqlConnection.query(sqlquery,(err,result)=>{
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }
            else{
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the queries does not depends each other is not neccesary you `await` the response.

Use `Promise.all` and the queries are going to run in parallel.

```
   Promise.all([selectquery(sqlquery),selectquery(sqlsecond),selectquery(sqlthird)])
          .then(res=> res.json({result1:res[0], result2:res[1], result3:res[2]});)
```

Comment: thanks for the help can you please tell me where should I use promise.all in my code.

Comment: In `getChartData` function. remove the responses variables and the return statement for the code i've posted.

Comment: the running time is still 56 seconds